# Java ObjectOutputStream's Method flush()

Tags: java, client-server, flush, objectoutputstream

I am currently learning networking, specifically client-server classes.
I have done much research and implemented various test programs but I can't figure out why/when one would need to use the flush() method.

How can there be data mistakenly left in the output stream if it is always read in by the input stream? As dictated by the client-server code.
I tried to test my basic echo client server program by omitting the flush() but I could not break it.

When testing the flush() by writing twice from the client side and only reading once for the server's reply all that happened was a backlog (I assume the stream acts like a queue?) in the server's replies.
Then I took the same code and added flush() before and after the second write and it made no difference. It's as if the flush() doesn't actually clear the stream.

So can someone please explain in what scenario with regards to client/server stream interactions would flush() be required?

Server:

```
public class ServerApp
{
    private ServerSocket listener;
    private Socket clientCon;

    public ServerApp()
    {
        try
        {
            listener = new ServerSocket(1234, 10);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void listen()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Server is listening!");
            clientCon = listener.accept();
            System.out.println("Server: Connection made with Client");

            processClient();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void processClient()
    {
        try(ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientCon.getOutputStream()); ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientCon.getInputStream()))
        {
            String msg;
            while(!(msg = (String)in.readObject()).equalsIgnoreCase("Shutdown"))
            {
                out.writeObject("Server: " + msg);
                out.flush();
            }
            out.writeObject("Server is powering down...");

            out.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        ServerApp sa = new ServerApp();
        sa.listen();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class ClientApp
{
    private Socket serverCon;

    public ClientApp()
    {
        try
        {
            serverCon = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void communicate()
    {
        try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(serverCon.getOutputStream()); ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(serverCon.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
        {
            String response = null;
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Enter your message for server: ");
                out.writeObject(br.readLine());

                out.flush();
                out.writeObject("Flush not working");
                out.flush();

                response = (String) in.readObject();
                System.out.println(response);

                response = (String) in.readObject();
                System.out.println(response);
            } while (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("Server is powering down..."));
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ClientApp ca = new ClientApp();
        ca.communicate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `flush()` is used to flush out any internal buffers that may be in use. For example using a `BufferedOutputStream` the contents are written in chunks to improve performance (it's slower to write each byte as they come).

Depending on usage, you might never have to call flush(). However let's say you send a small `String` (converted to `byte[]`) and it fits nicely in the internal buffer. The contents of the buffer won't be sent until the buffer is full or `flush()` is called.

Now let's say you're writing over the network, and you expect the other side to answer something to your small `String`. Since it's still in the buffer, the other side won't receive it and it can result in both sides waiting forever.

Object streams are another beast, and I'm a little disappointed that so many beginners are using them. There should be a warning in the class saying "Objects may be more difficult to send/receive than they appear".

`ObjectOutputStream` delegates the `flush()` call to its internal `BlockDataOutputStream` which has 3 buffers sized `1024`, `5` and `256` for "blockdata", header data and characters respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(clientCon.getOutputStream()))` and you'll see a difference with and without `flush().` It causes flushing of the underlying buffered output stream. Without a buffered stream there is no buffer to flush so it does nothing.

Comment: Strangely when I try using new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(clientCon.getOutputStream())) in the ServerApp then the ClientApp hangs(waits for input and does not print out "Enter message for server"). Is the message that I should be taking form this that you do not need to use flush() unless working with a Buffered stream?